# Is there any free IGS viewer?

Tags: viewer, cad

Are there any free or open source .IGS viewers that you've actually used on a regular basis?  There are a lot of Google hits, but they seem like they're all free trials, misdirection to other products, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling around I found [IGSViewer](http://igsviewer.com/), it's for Windows and should be free.

After a quick test it didn't work for the specific IGS file we were trying to view: there was just the outline but many internal details were missing. Don't know if the problem lies in the file or in the viewer, didn't try any harder *(we found a way to get the source, a DXF drawing from which someone also made the IGS one, and used a dxf viewer that worked really well)*